# How to get an index of a variable from func_interpr entry?

Tags: c++, c, api, z3

A function model contains entries of pairs `<condition_on_args, return_value>`.

The `return_value` expression may refer to input arguments, for example `(f!4 (k!3 (:var 0)))`. Here `(:var 0)` refers to the 0th input argument of the function model, and it is of kind Z3_VAR_AST.

I want to transform `return_value` to some internal program representation, but don't know how to relate `(:var 0)` to 0th input argument of the function model.

How to get an index of the variable, that is `0`, from expr `(:var 0)` of kind Z3_VAR_AST via c/c++ API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the following API:

```c
    /**
       \brief Return index of de-Brujin bound variable.

       \pre Z3_get_ast_kind(a) == Z3_VAR_AST

       def_API('Z3_get_index_value', UINT, (_in(CONTEXT), _in(AST)))
    */
    unsigned Z3_API Z3_get_index_value(__in Z3_context c, __in Z3_ast a);
```